# Options for ArcGIS Server and ArcSDE Hosting

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, remote-hosting

I know this was partially address [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11250/map-hosting-options), but it was not specific to ESRI products.  I want to find some place to create and host map services with ArcGIS Server and ArcSDE.  ESRI cloud options are bit pricey for the initial startup and testing of my project.  Anyone know of lower priced alternative?

Comment: There isn't one. ArcSDE and ArcServer are niche products that are expensive. I doubt that exists a hosting company that offers these for rent. The price is high, maintenance requires specialized people and there are many technical challenges to be solved so you can share a ArcGIS Server instance with more then two distinct users that should not see each other business.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Services division at Latitude Geographics does [ArcGIS Server hosting](http://www.geocortex.com/arcgis-server-services/arcgis-server-hosting/), but I have no idea what the cost is nor have I used it. I have used their Geocortex Essentials line and worked with them on custom ArcGIS Server web app development, and they are a great company with very talented developers, product managers, project managers - you name it. Give them a call, I'm sure they'd be happy to talk to you about options.

Comment: interesting. I wonder what the price is...

Comment: @George - I'm sure it varies depending on what you really need.

Answer (score 3):

[ROK Technologies](http://www.roktech.net/arcgis-server-hosting-and-cache-management.html) provides "ArcGIS Server hosting and map cache management." For more info on ArcGIS Server hosting see [here](http://www.roktech.net/_blog/ROK_Blog/post/ArcGIS_Server_Hosting/). I can't find a pricing guide, but you can [contact them](http://www.roktech.net/contact-us.html).

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a old thread, but @Baskinomics is right, ROK Technologies does host [ArcGIS Server map services](http://www.roktech.net/main/arcgis-server-hosting).

Full Disclosure..I work at ROK. Monthly fees are reasonable, and not based on a credit system - all are flat fee. Dont want to turn this into a plug, just letting you know that we do in fact do it.

Comment: yeah - times have changed since the original post.  Going all open source now: postgres/postgis, mapbox, etc on Amazon EC2.